# How can I get the total quantity of a sorted field in a data table with lnq?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I am attempting to use linq for my C# form to count the total quantity of the selected fields. However, the fields can be sorted by either stor_id or ord_num. I get syntax errors any time I attempt to write an or statement to get the total in my query. It works fine when I am only querying for either the stor_id or the ord_num, it is just combining them that causes the issue. This is what my query looks like now.

```
System.Nullable<double> total = (from ord in _Pubs_1_DataSet.sales where 
                                 (ord.ord_num == txtOrderNumber.Text 
                                 or ord.stor_id == txtStoreID.Text) 
                                 select (int)ord.qty).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or` is not the way. Just use `||` (which basically means `or`)

```
System.Nullable<double> total = (from ord in _Pubs_1_DataSet.sales where (ord.ord_num == txtOrderNumber.Text || ord.stor_id == txtStoreID.Text) select (int) ord.qty).Sum();
```

Comment: That makes sense, I was trying to write it like a sql query instead of with C# logic. Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 0):

`||` is for `or` in `C#`. Also I included `ord.qty.HasValue` in the query to filter `nullable` qty.

```
(from ord in _Pubs_1_DataSet.sales 
where ((ord.ord_num == txtOrderNumber.Text || ord.stor_id == txtStoreID.Text) && ord.qty.HasValue)
select ord.qty.Value).Sum();
```